# Persistent Counter in Spark App

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Kafka server that every `n` minutes produces data like this:

`[('a', 123), ('b', 87), ('c', 101)]`

I want my spark app to keep a counter of the form

`counter = {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}`

where the dictionary (or any other proper data structure) values are incremented if the pairs, e.g. `('a', score)`, have scores > 100 for instance.

The next time I consume data from Kafka, if the pair `(a, score)` has again a score > 100 I want `counter['a']` to be incremented by a unit so that it is equal to `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Accumulator with a Counter.

Build an accumulator:

```
from collections import Counter

class CounterAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):  
    def zero(self, value):  
        return {}
    def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
        val1.update(val2)
        return val1

accum_counter = sc.accumulator(Counter(),CounterAccumulatorParam())
```

And if you want to update the value of the accumulator just add a key-value pair to it:

```
accum_counter.add({key:num})
```

For your example:

```
rdd_test = sc.parallelize([('a', 123), ('b', 87), ('c', 101)])

accum = sc.accumulator(Counter(),CounterAccumulatorParam())

def add_func(x):
    if x[1]>100:
        accum.add({x[0]:1})

rdd_test.foreach(lambda x: add_func(x))


accum.value
# Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 1})
```

Comment: When tried it, I had to change `zero` method of `CounterAccumulatorParam` to:
     `return Counter()` instead of `return {}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
data = [('a', 123), ('b', 87), ('c', 101)]

from collections import Counter    ​
mycounter = Counter()         # initiate the Counter
```

Then use the `update` method to increase the count:

```
# update the counter with your transformed data
mycounter.update({k: 1 if v > 100 else 0 for k, v in data})    
mycounter
# Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1})
```

Second time update:

```
mycounter.update({k: 1 if v > 100 else 0 for k, v in data})
mycounter
# Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 2})
```

Comment: Isn't there a specific way to do this in spark so that to store this counter in an appropriate way?  I was thinking of broadcasting but not sure that'll do the trick.

Comment: So you want a global counter shared by all nodes? You can broadcast a variable by using `sc.broadcast()` but I am not sure if that is a good idea.

Comment: Yes I want the counter to be accessible by all nodes so that every time the spark app is run the counter is updated accordingly on all the nodes.

Comment: Counters is the proper way..    it will get persisted in checkpoints as well.